# How to avoid nesting navigators in React Native with nested screens and a single back button across levels

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

Here's what I am trying to achieve:

1. Multiple levels of nesting. Example: (Home, Settings, Profile) -> Inside Home: (Employees, Equipment, Activity) -> Inside Equipment: Add, View, Home -> Inside Add: Brand selection, options, metadata and so on
2. Inside Home, these (Employees, Equipment, Activity) will be bottom navigation tabs, inside each view rendered by these tabs they will have sub views.
3. A single "top bar" which will house a "Back" button that can go back across screens / nav levels, this button needs to dynamically adapt itself to the level of context which "makes sense".

Here are the problems I run into with React Navigation

- There seems to be no way I can avoid nesting navigators (which is discouraged in react navigation docs, citing performance) when my screens are nested. I can use a single navigator but I am not sure how to tie up this single navigator to the bottom navigation for some of these screens but other screens appear within those screens.
- With multiple (nested) navigators, the Back button on the header would need logic (and some kind of state) to keep track of which "level" to go back on. For example if the user goes back from Employees to Equipment, versus Add equipment back to Equipment home, and so on.

What I tried:

- I actually tried writing my own navigation solution which is a lightweight, flat system that uses a shared context, a history stack, a navigate method, a goBack method and a few frills. This actually works well. But I don't like reinventing the wheel and maintaining code I don't have to, so I am trying to see if I can move this to use React Navigation.

I think what I am describing is a fairly common use-case for an app. What is a recommended approach?

Comment: personally I still nest navigator if I need to use two or more different type of navigator like `StackNavigator` or `BottomTabNavigator`